# HTML purifier or php. Prevent stray li tags

Tags: php, html, sanitization, htmlpurifier

I need to prevent lonesome li tags in some html input (From users-RTE). Ideally any of these tags would just be removed, but HTML purifier seems to let it pass.

How can I either configure HTMLpurifer to remove these, or how can I remove these using just basic php?

example:

```
<li>bad text</li>
<ol><li>good text</li></ol>
```

would be turned into

```
<ol><li>good text</li></ol>
```

Comment: *To prevent "lonesome" tags, write tags carefully*

Comment: source of bad html is?

Comment: Rich text editor. It is user input.

Comment: _"but HTML purifier seems to let it pass."_ According to the demo on the website ( http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php ), `<li>bad text</li>` is usually turned into `bad text`. Is that not acceptable for your purposes or is that not what you're getting with your configuration? If latter, could you specify what configuration you're using?